# running command as local service (not user)

Tags: command-line, visual-sourcesafe

ss.exe command -I- won't run using local service

If I run the below command as a network user it works.

"C:\Program Files\SourceSafe\win32\SS.EXE" GET $/JavaSource -R -W -GL "d:\Release\com\fitltd" -GF- -O- -I- Set d:\Release\com\fitltd as the default folder for project $/JavaSource?(Y/N)N

However if this command is called using a local service user (Jenkins service) the command stops waiting for input (you can't see the question it is waiting (see above) for unless you run the same thing using a network user).

so the output looks like: "C:\Program Files\SourceSafe\win32\SS.EXE" GET $/JavaSource -R -W -GL "d:\Release\com\fitltd" -GF- -O- -I-

I am running Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add the command to the question not in the title and try to format it, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Please also attach the output.